# how to use upsert in SQLite

Tags: android

I have a table defined as follows:

VideoID INTEGER,PRIMARY KEY , Status TEXT

I want to update this table every time when user scrolls the list if there is new data for any videoID it should be updated otherwise if new videoIDfound it should be inserted in table

it is working well with insertWithOnConflict() but the problem is it also updates seen column every time with a default value which I don't want I want to store the seen status for a videoID which cant be changed

an alternative i tried is:

```
  String que="INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + TABLE_NAME + "("+VIDEOTITLE+","+VIDEO_ID+","+VIDEO_TIME+","
               +VIDEO_VIEW+","+VIDEO_AMOUNT+","+VIDEO_THUMB+","+VIDEO_URL+","+VIDEO_DETAILS+","+YOUTUBE_KEY+")"+" VALUES ( "+VIDEOTITLE+","+VIDEO_ID+","+VIDEO_TIME+","+VIDEO_VIEW+","+VIDEO_AMOUNT+","+VIDEO_THUMB+","+VIDEO_URL+
               ","+VIDEO_DETAILS+","+YOUTUBE_KEY+",(SELECT "+STATUS+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE videoId = "+ curr_id+" ));";
       db.execSQL(que);
```

but this is not executing.
curr_id is the videoId.

Comment: see `SQLiteDatabase#replace`

Comment: The no of column name did not match with the no of values

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately SQLite doesn't support `insert or replace`.

You can use the `on conflict replace` to achieve a similar behaviour. You can read more about it [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).

Keep in mind that `on conflict replace` will actually delete the existing record and create another one. That means that, if you are using an autoincrement column for you primary key, you will get a different record and not update the existing one.

If you want to keep the identity of the record intact, you may have to look into other, more complex options.

Comment: i have already used insert with on conflict () but this is updating my all fields which i dont want i want something that will leave seen column of table and update all other fields

Comment: no i am looking for it right now how to use it in this case

Comment: replace command will delete the old existing record and insert again but my problem is still the same seen column will also be updated which i dont want

Comment: i dont want to update the status column of table once it was set to seen i dont want to replace this column's value while replacing

Comment: can u give me an example for what i want to do with replace()

Comment: @swarnima Then why don't you just use a simple update and set only the `seen` column to the value you need?

Comment: @swarnima If you get 0 rows updated, then the record is missing and you can do an insert.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev if i use this with update seen column is updated but at the same time i also want to update all other fields of table then seen column is updated to default value again.The thing is i want to update all the fields of a table except seen column and if a new id found then insert it to the table

Comment: @swarnima Ok, so, again, why don't you try this. You use `update` the columns you want by `videoId`. If no records are updated, the `update()` method will return 0. This means that this `videoId` is missing, and then you can do an `insert` to create the new record.